# chain and order from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

- **Size** that `belongs_to: :product`
- **Product** that `has_many: :sizes` and that `belongs_to: :category`
- **Category** that `has_many: :products`

I want sort them in a table in my Products index
by Category title, then by product title, then by size

```
Caegories | Product | Size |
----------------------------
   A      |   A     | S    |
   A      |   A     | M    |
   A      |   B     | S    |
   A      |   C     | S    |
   B      |   A     | S    |
   B      |   A     | M    |
   B      |   B     | S    |
   B      |   C     | S    |
```

How I am supposed to chain and order all this? is it possible?

> update

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", limit: 100, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end


create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", limit: 150, null: false
    t.decimal "price", precision: 15, scale: 2, default: "0.0", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.json "attachments"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
  end

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "size_name"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_sizes_on_product_id"
  end
```

I think I'd rather start ordering from Size in order to display each size...
But I dont know how...

index.html.erb

```
<% "my query???".each do |size| %>
    <td><%= size.product.category.title %></td>
    <td><%= size.product.title %></td>
    <td><%= size.product.price %></td>
    <td><%= size.size_name %></td>
    <td><%= size.quantity %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It will be better if you do it on client side . use any third party plugin in which you are able to add sorting in table  for an example https://datatables.net/

Comment: You think @Vishal? I'd definitely want to do this in the backend...

Comment: I am sure, it will be very tricky if you are going to manage data in this style . which query will you run to get data with this sorting ?

Comment: I've updated my question with my schema and the index I want to have

Comment: Just to store `quantity` & `size`, creating `sizes` table is real bad OOAD. You could store these 2 values inside `products` table.

Comment: That's what I did first, but the admin had to create a product per size... So it was too long to input for him. 
Like this he creates a product and in the nested fields he enters size_name and quantity for each size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @ray's answer is solid for the most part, I think you'll need to plug in something extra to get the sizes ordered as expected, i.e. 'small, medium, large'.

In ray's answer, this would be alphabetical, while I imagine you'd want this to be from small to large or vice versa.

This would make your query look something like the following:

```
Product.joins(:category, :sizes).order("categories.title, title").order("CASE sizes.size_name WHEN 'SMALL' THEN 'a' WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 'b' WHEN 'LARGE' THEN 'c' ELSE 'z' END ASC")
```

I've chained `order` separately for the `CASE` statement for readability, though you could also do something like:

```
Product.joins(:category, :sizes).order("categories.title, title, CASE sizes.size_name WHEN 'SMALL' THEN 'a' WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 'b' WHEN 'LARGE' THEN 'c' ELSE 'z' END ASC")
```

---

Personally speaking, I'd go a step further with this and store the sizes as an [`enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) column in the db if at all possible:

```
enum size_name: [:small, :medium, :large] 
# Or enum size_name: { small: 0, medium: 1, large: 2 }
```

This makes the code very simple as the enum column stores an integer in order of the above:

```
Product.joins(:category, :sizes).order("categories.title, title, sizes.size_name")
```

Finally, this has bonus points: you'll have access to methods such as `Size.medium`, `size.medium?`, `size.large!` and so on :)

Hope this helps - let me know if you've any questions or comments!

---

**Edit based on update to question**

To start with the `Size`, you would tweak to one of the following:

```
Size.joins(product: :category).order("CASE sizes.size_name WHEN 'SMALL' THEN 'a' WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 'b' WHEN 'LARGE' THEN 'c' ELSE 'z' END ASC").order("categories.title, products.title")
```

Or with `enum`:

```
Size.joins(product: :category).order("sizes.size_name, categories.title, products.title")
```

Comment: I think he could store size in products table column to reduce complexity. Answer is as per his requirement but improvement in existing schema could help much better.

Comment: Size is a nested attribute for product it is manually entered by the admin, it can be either _small_, _medium_, _s_,  _m_,  _38/40_, _40/42_  
It really depends on the articles...

Comment: Huh, in which case maybe alphabetical is sufficient? In which case, go with @ray's approach :) Alternatively, you could add a `position` attribute to `sizes` (perhaps using something like [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) and order by that.

Comment: yes or by created_at ( as the admin will enter from the smallest tto the largest...)

Comment: Ha, I'd not be inclined to trust 'em on that :)

Comment: `Size.joins(product: :category).order("categories.title ASC,  products.title ASC, sizes.created_at ASC ")` made the job I expected. 
many thanks to all of you for the precious help

Comment: Great, glad it's up and running :) Happy to have helped, hope it goes well from here!

Comment: `enum` was not in my mind but I would also like to prefer enum if it were my case, well explained!

Answer (score 2):

I did not test following but must work,

I did not get your `sizes` table schema properly. Assuming `Size` model have column `type` to store values like L(large), S(small) & M(medium).

```
Product.joins(:category, :sizes).order('categories.title, title, sizes.type')
```

Make sure your associations and table schema are proper

**Note:** AS per your updated schema,

```
Product.joins(:category, :sizes).order('categories.title, title, sizes.size_name')
```